# jQuery is selecting wrong elements during on click action

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I have the following code example here:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.children a.txtlink').on("click", function(e) {
    // toggle the icons when the text link is pressed

    jQuery(this).parent().find('ul:first').toggle(); // toggle the next UL

    if (jQuery(this).parent().find('i').hasClass("fa-chevron-down")) {
      jQuery(this).parent().find('i').removeClass("fa-chevron-down").addClass("fa-chevron-up");
    } else {
      jQuery(this).parent().find('i').removeClass("fa-chevron-up").addClass("fa-chevron-down");
    }

    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  $('.children i.arrows').on("click", function(e) {
    // toggle the icons when the chevron is pressed

    jQuery(this).parent().find('ul:first').toggle(); // toggle the next UL

    if (jQuery(this).hasClass("fa-chevron-down")) {
      jQuery(this).removeClass("fa-chevron-down").addClass("fa-chevron-up");
    } else {
      jQuery(this).removeClass("fa-chevron-up").addClass("fa-chevron-down");
    }

    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  });


});
```

```css
.navbar_menu {
  background: #222222;
}

.menu {
  border-top: 1px solid #2D2D2D;
}

.menu ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.menu li {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}

.menu li i {
  padding-right: 3px;
}

.menu a.txtlink {
  color: #ccc;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-right: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #2D2D2D;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu a.txtlink:hover {
  background: #111111;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu li.home a.txtlink::before {
  content: '\f015';
  display: inline-block;
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
  font-size: inherit;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  transform: none;
}

.menu ul li {
  position: relative;
}

.menu ul li.children i.arrows {
  /* needed to show an icon in the mobile menu */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 14px;
  border-left: 1px solid #333333;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  color: #CCCCCC;
}

.menu .sub {
  display: none;
}

.menu ul li ul li a.txtlink {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.menu ul li ul li ul li a.txtlink {
  padding-left: 40px;
}

.menu i.arrows:hover {
  background-color: #111111;
}

.menu ul li ul li {
  background-color: #333333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar_menu">

  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li class="home"><a href="#" class="txtlink">Home</a></li>
      <li class="children">
        <a href="#" class="txtlink"><i class="fa fa-folder"></i>Menu 1</a>
        <ul class="sub">
          <li class="children">
            <a href="#" class="txtlink"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>Menu 1.1</a>
            <ul class="sub">
              <li><a href="#" class="txtlink"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>Menu 1.1.1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="txtlink"><i class="fa fa-tag"></i>Menu 1.1.2</a></li>
            </ul>
            <i class="arrows fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#" class="txtlink">Menu 1.2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="txtlink">Menu 1.3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="txtlink"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>Menu 1.4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="txtlink"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>Menu 1.5</a></li>
        </ul>
        <i class="arrows fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" class="txtlink"><i class="fa "></i>Menu 2</a></li>
      <li class="children">
        <a href="#" class="txtlink"><i class="fa fa-folder"></i>Menu 3</a>
        <ul class="sub">
          <li class="children">
            <a href="#" class="txtlink"><i class="fa fa fa-search"></i>Menu 3.1</a>
            <ul class="sub">
              <li><a href="#" class="txtlink"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>Menu 3.1.1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="txtlink"><i class="fa fa-bookmark-o"></i>Menu 3.1.2</a></li>
            </ul>
            <i class="arrows fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#" class="txtlink"><i class="fa"></i>Menu 3.2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="txtlink"><i class="fa"></i>Menu 3.3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="txtlink"><i class="fa fa fa-calendar"></i>Menu 3.4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="txtlink"><i class="fa fa fa-search"></i>Menu 3.5</a></li>
        </ul>
        <i class="arrows fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" class="txtlink"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i>Menu 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</nav>
```

The issue is that it works fine when i use the small arrows to expand/shrink the menu and the arrows are swapped correctly. However when I click on the text element then the icons in the menu are all replaced with the arrow.

Example: When using the arrows the search icon stays in the menu. When i click on the text link it is replaced with an arrow.

I think i have used here an wrong jquery selector but as I´m quite new to jquery i´m unable to get it fixed. So what is my error here?

When I click on the arrows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `.children()` instead of `.find()` to ensure that only direct
   children are included in the query.
2. Your onclick event can be combined
   into 1 single event listener with `$('.children > a.txtlink,
   .children > i.arrows')`. Again, use the `>` direct child selector to
   ensure that we're not querying nested children.

It should work as expected now:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.children > a.txtlink, .children > i.arrows').on("click", function(e) {
    // toggle the icons when the text link is pressed

    jQuery(this).parent().children('ul:first').toggle(); // toggle the next UL

    if (jQuery(this).parent().children('i.arrows').hasClass("fa-chevron-down")) {
      jQuery(this).parent().children('i.arrows').removeClass("fa-chevron-down").addClass("fa-chevron-up");
    } else {
      jQuery(this).parent().children('i.arrows').removeClass("fa-chevron-up").addClass("fa-chevron-down");
    }

    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```css
.navbar_menu {
  background: #222222;
}

.menu {
  border-top: 1px solid #2D2D2D;
}

.menu ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.menu li {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}

.menu li i {
  padding-right: 3px;
}

.menu a.txtlink {
  color: #ccc;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-right: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #2D2D2D;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu a.txtlink:hover {
  background: #111111;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu li.home a.txtlink::before {
  content: '\f015';
  display: inline-block;
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
  font-size: inherit;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  transform: none;
}

.menu ul li {
  position: relative;
}

.menu ul li.children i.arrows {
  /* needed to show an icon in the mobile menu */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 14px;
  border-left: 1px solid #333333;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  color: #CCCCCC;
}

.menu .sub {
  display: none;
}

.menu ul li ul li a.txtlink {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.menu ul li ul li ul li a.txtlink {
  padding-left: 40px;
}

.menu i.arrows:hover {
  background-color: #111111;
}

.menu ul li ul li {
  background-color: #333333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar_menu">

  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li class="home"><a href="#" class="txtlink">Home</a></li>
      <li class="children">
        <a href="#" class="txtlink"><i class="fa fa-folder"></i>Menu 1</a>
        <ul class="sub">
          <li class="children">
            <a href="#" class="txtlink"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>Menu 1.1</a>
            <ul class="sub">
              <li><a href="#" class="txtlink"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>Menu 1.1.1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="txtlink"><i class="fa fa-tag"></i>Menu 1.1.2</a></li>
            </ul>
            <i class="arrows fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#" class="txtlink">Menu 1.2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="txtlink">Menu 1.3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="txtlink"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>Menu 1.4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="txtlink"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>Menu 1.5</a></li>
        </ul>
        <i class="arrows fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" class="txtlink"><i class="fa "></i>Menu 2</a></li>
      <li class="children">
        <a href="#" class="txtlink"><i class="fa fa-folder"></i>Menu 3</a>
        <ul class="sub">
          <li class="children">
            <a href="#" class="txtlink"><i class="fa fa fa-search"></i>Menu 3.1</a>
            <ul class="sub">
              <li><a href="#" class="txtlink"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>Menu 3.1.1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="txtlink"><i class="fa fa-bookmark-o"></i>Menu 3.1.2</a></li>
            </ul>
            <i class="arrows fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#" class="txtlink"><i class="fa"></i>Menu 3.2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="txtlink"><i class="fa"></i>Menu 3.3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="txtlink"><i class="fa fa fa-calendar"></i>Menu 3.4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="txtlink"><i class="fa fa fa-search"></i>Menu 3.5</a></li>
        </ul>
        <i class="arrows fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" class="txtlink"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i>Menu 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, good job at attempting this and supplying the code.  That said, there is a lot of ways to improve this, which I don't have the time to get into, but have made a few changes to bridge that gap:

1. Use variables to make the code more efficient and easier to read.  Storing `$(this)` and `$(this).parent()` are two musts in your code
2. The heart of your problem has come with `$parent.find('i').hasClass('fa-chevron-down')`, which is locating all the `<i>` elements under that parent and if any has that class, it's going to be true.  I quickly changed this to only look for `i.fa-chevron-down`, but using `jQuery.children()` may also be a better option
3. To avoid `$` collisions, it's a good rule of thumb to avoid `$(document).ready` and use `jQuery(document).ready`; the `$` can then be used internally, if you call the named parameter it; for instance `.ready(function($){`

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.children a.txtlink').on("click", function(e) {
    // toggle the icons when the text link is pressed

    var $this = $(this),
      $parent = $this.parent(),
      $ul = $parent.find('ul:first');

    $ul.toggle(); // toggle the next UL

    if ($parent.find('i.fa-chevron-down').length) {
      $parent.find('i.fa-chevron-down').removeClass("fa-chevron-down").addClass("fa-chevron-up");
    } else {
      $parent.find('i.fa-chevron-up').removeClass("fa-chevron-up").addClass("fa-chevron-down");
    }

    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  $('.children i.arrows').on("click", function(e) {
    // toggle the icons when the chevron is pressed
    
    var $this = $(this),
      $parent = $this.parent(),
      $ul = $parent.find('ul:first');

    $ul.toggle(); // toggle the next UL

    if ($this.hasClass("fa-chevron-down")) {
      $this.removeClass("fa-chevron-down").addClass("fa-chevron-up");
    } else {
      $this.removeClass("fa-chevron-up").addClass("fa-chevron-down");
    }

    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  });


});
```

```css
.navbar_menu {
  background: #222222;
}

.menu {
  border-top: 1px solid #2D2D2D;
}

.menu ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.menu li {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}

.menu li i {
  padding-right: 3px;
}

.menu a.txtlink {
  color: #ccc;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-right: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #2D2D2D;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu a.txtlink:hover {
  background: #111111;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu li.home a.txtlink::before {
  content: '\f015';
  display: inline-block;
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
  font-size: inherit;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  transform: none;
}

.menu ul li {
  position: relative;
}

.menu ul li.children i.arrows {
  /* needed to show an icon in the mobile menu */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 14px;
  border-left: 1px solid #333333;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  color: #CCCCCC;
}

.menu .sub {
  display: none;
}

.menu ul li ul li a.txtlink {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.menu ul li ul li ul li a.txtlink {
  padding-left: 40px;
}

.menu i.arrows:hover {
  background-color: #111111;
}

.menu ul li ul li {
  background-color: #333333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar_menu">

  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li class="home"><a href="#" class="txtlink">Home</a></li>
      <li class="children">
        <a href="#" class="txtlink"><i class="fa fa-folder"></i>Menu 1</a>
        <ul class="sub">
          <li class="children">
            <a href="#" class="txtlink"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>Menu 1.1</a>
            <ul class="sub">
              <li><a href="#" class="txtlink"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>Menu 1.1.1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="txtlink"><i class="fa fa-tag"></i>Menu 1.1.2</a></li>
            </ul>
            <i class="arrows fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#" class="txtlink">Menu 1.2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="txtlink">Menu 1.3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="txtlink"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>Menu 1.4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="txtlink"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>Menu 1.5</a></li>
        </ul>
        <i class="arrows fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" class="txtlink"><i class="fa "></i>Menu 2</a></li>
      <li class="children">
        <a href="#" class="txtlink"><i class="fa fa-folder"></i>Menu 3</a>
        <ul class="sub">
          <li class="children">
            <a href="#" class="txtlink"><i class="fa fa fa-search"></i>Menu 3.1</a>
            <ul class="sub">
              <li><a href="#" class="txtlink"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>Menu 3.1.1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="txtlink"><i class="fa fa-bookmark-o"></i>Menu 3.1.2</a></li>
            </ul>
            <i class="arrows fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#" class="txtlink"><i class="fa"></i>Menu 3.2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="txtlink"><i class="fa"></i>Menu 3.3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="txtlink"><i class="fa fa fa-calendar"></i>Menu 3.4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="txtlink"><i class="fa fa fa-search"></i>Menu 3.5</a></li>
        </ul>
        <i class="arrows fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" class="txtlink"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i>Menu 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</nav>
```